# Array of Buttons (Android)

Tags: java, android, arrays, button

I have an array of buttons in my Android app.  I want pressing a button to cause a different button to turn white.  I have code like this:

```
final Button [][] button = new Button[5][3];

for(int i = 0; i < tableRow.length; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < button[i].length; j++) {
        button[i][j] = new Button(this);
        button[i][j].getBackground().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0x00000000, 0xFF000000));
    }
}

button[0][0].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        button[0][0].getBackground().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0x00000000, 0x00FFFFFF));
    }
});
```

This works fine, but it turns button[0][0] white when it is pressed, while I want pressing button[0][0] to turn button[0][1] white.  If I change it to this:

```
button[0][0].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        button[0][1].getBackground().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0x00000000, 0x00FFFFFF));
    }
});
```

nothing happens when I press button[0][0].  Why?

Comment: reload the view after changing color

Comment: @BillGary How do you reload the view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
button[0][1].invalidate();
```

will force the view to get redrawn.